# TextMesh Pro problem while Using Unity 2018?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a little problem, I had always a GDPR package that I always import and add it to my project, but I was working with Unity 2018.2.2 and I finished my little game, I tried to add this package but I get this error, that I think I know why it pops up but I have no idea how to solve it, it said :

```
C:/Users/eichl/AppData/Local/Unity/cache/packages/packages.unity.com
/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.2.4/Scripts/Runtime/TMPro_Private.cs(3551,92): 
error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or     
properties: TMPro.TMPro_ExtensionMethods.Compare(this 
UnityEngine.Color32, UnityEngine.Color32)' and 
TMPro.TMPro_ExtensionMethods.Compare(this UnityEngine.Color32, UnityEngine.Color32)'
```

I wish I can find some help, I heard some answers, someone said that I ned to remove the TextMesh Pro package from Unity Folder ( Users/taouf/AppData/Roaming/Unity/AssetStore-5.x\Unity Technologies\Unity EssentialsBeta Content ) But I didnt find it ..

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you look into the ouput it says the file you are looking for is in

`C:/Users/eichl/AppData/Local/Unity/...` not in `AppData/Roaming`; did you look there too?

Comment: I've gotten tons of these errors too.  On 2 projects with 2018.  The errors I received were "TMPro_<Classname>.<Method> has no overriding method".  This occurred on one project when I switched my build from mono to ILCPP but I still have never been able to recover.  Sorry I'm no help just a fellow in frustration.

Comment: derHugo : Well; I found a solution, I went to 'C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Unity/cache/packages/packages.unity.com and there there is a folder called textProMesh.. JUST DELETED IT and the errors has gone..

Comment: jiveturkey : I fixed my problem, check my answer ..